# Response.End doesnot render javascript

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse, response.write

On the click of the button my Onclick event gets fired.
Inside the onclick event I generate somefile at runtime and render it to the browser in the following way. But before rendering it to the browser I am making particular Label visible. But still the Label never become visible. Any idea what is the problem

```
    lblInfoMessage.Visible=true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.gxml");
    doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Already implemented , but still not getting the desired result

Comment: where have you set the visible property of the label to false ???is it during run time or by default in the design page

Comment: At run time before setting Response.ContetType

Comment: what happens if u put it below Response.End()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **either** refresh the page (and thus change visibility or contents of controls) **or** send an attachment. Not both. So you will have to find some other way, maybe client side javascript?

**EDIT**
In the button you need a OnClientClick in the server side code, this will translate into a client-side "onclick". Here you can call a javascript function where you can (for instance) display some text. Note that this function is executed *before* the submit action that will generate the file.

Something like this in the html/aspx:

```
<span id="infoMessage"><!-- empty --></span>
...
<asp:Button OnClientClick="showInfo()" ... />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showInfo() {
    document.getElementById("infoMessage").innerText = 
        "This is the info message.";

  }
</script>
```

You can't just show that Label that you have now, as that doesn't exist in the client-side html when it is invisible.

Comment: Can u help me with sample code for refreshing the page from javascript

Answer (score 0):

should it not be as below?

```
  lblInfoMessage.Visible=true;
```

Comment: It is the same as u mentioned. Sorry for the typo mistake

Comment: what happens if you remove `Response.End();` ?

Comment: If I remove the Response.End than some garbage values get added to the File which I am generating at runtime and makes the unreadable as it is a xml file.